# Google Dialogflow matching wrong intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm currently trying to develop a simple text bot using Google [Dialogflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogflow) for a school project.
This bot is intended to answer users' questions about a CPU visual simulator.

I've set an entity called @components which has:

"alu","arithmetic logic unit","alu","arithmetic unit"

"cpu","cpu","central processing unit","processing unit","processor"

and names of other components

I'm experiencing this problem in which if I ask the agent "what is an alu?" (which is one of the training questions I've set for the ALU_INFO intent). It matches the CPU_INFO intent (which does not have a single training question containing the entity "alu").

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are 'alu' and 'cpu' keys? Otherwise they ought to be [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) and [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit).

Answer (score 0):

This can be a common issue when entities aren't defined properly.

If all the training questions are based on what is a and the keyword isn't matched to an entity on dialogflow the first intent matched will be provided.

It should be fine once ALU, CPU... are all entity values.

You can also test the bot and see what the entity values are being filled as to figure out what could be improved on your training questions format.

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"based on what is a"*.